# Why does \setlength\**sep{**} in itemize environment not work as will?

Tags: spacing, itemize

I want to use **itemize** in my paper. Since I have found the separation in itemize is too loose, I want to make the items more tight to each other as well as to the the text. The original look is like below:

[image]

Firstly, I defined a new environment so that I could conveniently use it to get what I wanted. I tried like below

```tex
\newenvironment{ntitemize}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength\parsep{0em}
        \setlength\itemsep{0em}
        \setlength\topsep{0em}
        \setlength\partopsep{0em}
}{\end{itemize}}
```

After I using the **ntitemize** environmrnt to replace the itemize, the item changed to below:

[image]

It seemed that the itemsep just became a little bit more tight than the former, but the topsep seemed no any changes.

Then I tested the \setlength configuration like below:

```tex
\begin{itemize}
        \setlength\parsep{0em}
        \setlength\itemsep{0em}
        \setlength\topsep{0em}
        \setlength\partopsep{0em}
        \item 当该物体的大小形状对所研究的运动没有影响；
        \item 该物体某一点的运动能代替整个物体的运动时。
        \begin{itemize}
            \item A
            \item B
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
```

The effect seemed to be the same as the ntitemize environment.

Hence, I want to know what other parameters are controling these separation and how can I improve my code to get a tight itemize environment. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Is there are reason for not loading the `enumitem` package and simply replacing both instances of `\begin{itemize}`with `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`?

Comment: Thanks,  I've forgotten that package. Well, the `enumitem` package work well, but I still want to figure out  what makes my cofiguration which looks no problem(as I think) not work as my will. I'd appreciate it if someone can give me a answer.

Comment: those lengths are used by the list code to set up the required settings for the list, but most of them are already used and setting them inside the list will just affect nested lists